# how to read (Point) and Object otherObject syntax in a class

Tags: java

I'm new to learn java. I see this syntax in a Java class called 'Point', and I'm confused what it means, and what it does:

```
Point otherPoint = (Point) otherObject;
```

Thx !

Comment: It is called typecasting

Answer (score 0):

> I see this syntax in a Java class called 'Point', and I'm confused
>   what it means, and what it does:

Alright, let's break it down step by step:

this is the type of the object to reference:

```
Point
```

this is the identifier which refers to the object on the right side of the assignment operator:

```
otherPoint
```

this is known as casting:

```
(Point) otherObject;
```

Casting is the process of taking an Object of one particular type and “turning it into” another Object type.

if the cast succeeds the identifier `otherPoint` will refer to the object if not a [**`ClassCastException`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) exception will be thrown.

```
Point otherPoint = (Point) otherObject;
```

further reading:

- [**Casting in Java**](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/)
- [**What is casting in java?**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-casting-in-java)

Comment: thanks, but still confused what it does

Comment: ah, thanks, I see now ! thanks for pointing in the right direction !